# Failed to create service after deleting AWS ECS cluster mistakenly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

So I accidentally deleted the cluster. Now I am trying to create services again by using the same task definitions but I keep getting this error

`ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve ECR registry auth: service`